# Implementing rxjs Timeout with observable

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I am trying to Implement timeout with my http observable, but I don't think I'm handing the request correctly.

```
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';


//POST form 
  submitForm(data,authToken){
    //console.log(data,authToken);
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            'Authorization': authToken
          })
 };
  return this.http.post(this.apisubmitFormUrl, JSON.stringify(data),
        httpOptions||{reportProgress:true})
        .retry(3)
        .timeout(15000)
        .delay(2000);

  }
```

From other page

```
this.stemAPI.submitForm(this.submitData,this.reap.token).subscribe((result) =>{  
   //handle response
   }, (err) => 
    { 
   //handle error
 });
```

Comment: And why do you not think you're handling the request correctly?

Comment: Well the timeout function I feel isn't working. I've been testing and when I create an instance that the API requests takes longer than the timeout, I don't get any response or anything.

Comment: It should go into the error handler if the response takes longer than the timeout

Comment: That's what I assumed, but for some reason it's not doing that.

Comment: When I tried this in Stackblitz, it seemed to work fine...

Comment: Okay, maybe it's my testing method. Would this work if the user has little to no internet connection while trying to hit the api?

Comment: If the Observable does not emit a value within that timeout period, then yes it should cause an error

Comment: Okay, I thank you! I will do more testing. I apologize on the question, I just had a feeling something in my code was not correct.